# Why do the commands apt-cache showpkg and apt-cache show display different results in Linux?

Tags: linux, apt-get

I am looking to update a particular package on several Linux systems however when I run the commands `apt-cache showpkg {name_of_package}` it displays a higher version of the package is available e.g. v1.1 however when I run the command `apt-cache show {name_of_package}` it displays an older version e.g. v1.

Comment: It shouldn't... showpkg is just supposed to show more detail. Unless you're not scrolling back far enough, can you post the output of both commands for say the apache2 package? That may give some more insight into what the problem is.

Comment: @Zeroedout - Since I updated to the latest version of flash, I don't get the same result as I did before the update however posted another question which included the output - http://superuser.com/questions/422734/what-do-inst-and-conf-refer-to-when-using-the-command-apt-get-in-linux