# What do Inst and Conf refer to when using the command apt-get in Linux?

Tags: linux, apt-get

When I run the command `apt-get install flashplugin-installer` I am displayed the following lines of details

```
Inst flashplugin-installer [11.2.202.233ubuntu0.11.04.3] (11.2.202.235ubuntu0.11.04.1 Ubuntu:11.04/natty-updates [i386])
Conf flashplugin-installer (11.2.202.235ubuntu0.11.04.1 Ubuntu:11.04/natty-updates [i386])
```

What do `Inst` and `Conf` refer to? I am guessing `Inst` means installed however how does this relate to `Conf`? Does it mean confirm the installation of the said package?

Also why is the first package surrounded by square brackets e.g. `[` whilst the second package is surrounded by brackets e.g. `(`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it means configure. As in, after it installed it, it configured it. -- [See here](http://mancoosi.org/~abate/aptget-installation-plan)

As to square brackets `[]` versus parenthesis `()`, I believe it is showing the installed version when in the install output, but in the configure line, it is only showing the only version installed and does not need to prepend that information. Inst is the Conf line, with just the [version] attached.